# Payment Flow using Square Credit Card Reader

Tags: square-connect

We are creating an iPad app for our restaurant so that customers can order from their table without a waiter. We would like to use Square so that the customer can swipe their credit card to make the payment. Is it possible to use the Square credit card reader to accept and process payments while keeping the order flow within our app (in other words can we accept payments via Square without using the Square POS app on the iPad)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Square Register API might be appropriate for your needs. It enables an iOS app to quickly switch to Square Register to process an in-person payment (then switch back to the original app).

Register API is available for iOS and Android. Any developer can use it: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-overview/